# Rails not Date.strptime not getting accurate op

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

`07/28/2017 11:56 PM` This is my date and below is my current code:

`Date.strptime("07/28/2017 11:56 PM", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p').to_time`

i'm getting `o/p => 2017-07-28 00:00:00 +0530`  but i want hours.What exactly should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're converting it into a `Date` object which doesn't have any `time` component and then converting it back into a `Time` object. Instead, you can use either

```
Time.strptime("07/28/2017 11:56 PM", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
# => 2017-07-28 23:56:00 -0700
```

or

```
DateTime.strptime("07/28/2017 11:56 PM", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
# => Fri, 28 Jul 2017 23:56:00 +0000
```

and you call call `to_time` on the `DateTime` if you'd like

```
DateTime.strptime("07/28/2017 11:56 PM", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p').to_time
# => 2017-07-28 23:56:00 +0000
```